# How to properly insert mask into original image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, mask

My goal is to cover a face with circular noise (salt and pepper/black and white dots), however what I have managed to achieve is just rectangular noise.

I found the face coordinates (x,y,w,h) = `[389, 127, 209, 209]`
And using this [function](https://github.com/ArtLabss/open-data-anonimizer/blob/main/anonympy/images/core.py) added noise 
Like:

```py
img = cv2.imread('like_this.jpg')
x,y,w,h = [389, 127, 209, 209]

noised = add_noise(img[y:y+h,x:x+w])
new = img.copy()
new[y:y+h,x:x+w]  = noised

cv2.imshow('new', new)
```

[image: new.jpg]

From `x,y,w,h` I found that I want my circle to be at `(493, 231)` with radius 105

I researched I found something about masking and bitwise operations, so I tried:

```
mask = np.zeros(new.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
cv2.circle(mask, (493, 231), 105, 255, -1)

new_gray = cv2.cvtColor(new, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(new_gray, new_gray , mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('masked', masked)
```

[image: masked.jpg]

Here, the problem arises:

```py
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
OR = cv2.bitwise_or(masked, img_gray) # removes the black dots, idk why 

cv2.imshow('bitwise - OR', OR)
```

[image]

The black dots get removed from the noise and besides that, I can't seem to convert `OR` back to BGR.

Maybe there is a better way to do that.

Please, help/guidance needed!

Comment: `img[mask > 0] = noised[mask > 0]`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Hey, thankssss. I guessed right that you meant 
`img[mask > 0] = new[mask > 0]` and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh great, now I've gotta write an answer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is how to use masking. There are two options, `numpy` and OpenCV.

### numpy

Since you copied the noisy area into the result and now want to restore everything *outside of* the circle, I'll use `mask == 0` to get a boolean array that is true everywhere outside of the circle.

[image: mask] [image: ~mask]

With numpy, boolean arrays can be used as indices. The result is a "view", it behaves like a slice. Operations through it affect the original data.

```
noised = add_noise(img[y:y+h,x:x+w])
new = img.copy()
new[y:y+h,x:x+w] = noised # whole rectangle affected

new[mask == 0] = img[mask == 0] # restore everything outside of the circle
```

All three arrays (`mask, new, img`) need to have the same shape.

### OpenCV, masks

Not much point to it with Python and numpy available, but many of its C++ APIs take an optional `mask` argument that modifies that function's operation. `Mat::copyTo()` is one such method.

### OpenCV, bitwise operations

With bitwise operations, the mask would no longer just label each pixel as true or false, but it would have to be 3-channels and all eight bits of every value count, so it must contain only 0 and 255 (0xFF).

I'll erase everything outside of the circle first, then *add* back the part of the source that is outside of the circle. Both operations use `bitwise_and`. Two operations are required because bitwise operations can't just "overwrite". They react to both operands. I'll also use numpy's `~` operator to bitwise-negate the mask.

```
bitwise_mask = cv.cvtColor(mask, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) # blow it up
new = cv.bitwise_and(new, bitwise_mask)
new += cv.bitwise_and(img, ~bitwise_mask)
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise opperations function on binary conditions turning "off" a pixel if it has a value of zero, and turning it "on" if the pixel has a value greater than zero.

In your case the bitwise_or "removes" both the black background of the mask and the black points of the noise.

I propose to do it like this:

```
# Read image
img = cv2.imread('like_this.jpg')
x,y,w,h = [389, 127, 209, 209]

# Add squared noise
noised = add_noise(img[y:y+h,x:x+w])
new = img.copy()
new[y:y+h,x:x+w] = noised

# Transform the image to graylevel
new_gray = cv2.cvtColor(new, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Create a mask in which black noise is equal to 0 and white to 2
mask = np.zeros(new.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
mask[new_gray==0] = 1
mask[new_gray==255] = 2

# Mask the previous mask with a circle
circle = np.zeros(new.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
circle = cv2.circle(circle, (493, 231), 105, 1, -1)
mask = mask * circle

plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()

# Join the mask adding the noise to the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray[mask==1] = 0
gray[mask==2] = 255

cv2.imshow('Result', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: circle mask]

[image: final image]

Hope it works. If you need more help let me know.